# Adding PHP application to ASP.NET website using master pages

Tags: php, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I recently created a website using ASP.NET as I wanted to learn more about this language. I have more recently started learning about PHP and would like to include some php content on this website. I found the VS extension PHP Tools for Visual Studio and thought it might help.

I naively created a PHP page within my previously existing website, and assigned the master page when creating it, called Test.php, and added the master page to this file:

Test.php:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Navigation.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.php.cs" Inherits="Test" %>

<?php
      echo "Hello World!"; 
?>
```

but the output is this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Navigation.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.php.cs" Inherits="Test" %> Hello World!
```

so obviously it is not able to properly parse and display this website. I guess as it is using the php extension it has no idea what ASP.NET stuff is doing there. Does anyone have an idea how I can create a php page using this tool that can also be used within the context of master pages?

Comment: The extension adds editor features, what you're trying to do would be a server feature: letting a file get parsed by two language services (ASP.NET and PHP). I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Is there some sort of workaround possibly? Like using an iframe within an aspx file?

Comment: An `iframe` would work, but you wouldn't be able to share data/state/code server-side. They'd work like two separate applications.

Comment: You could use an iframe but you need to make sure the server you are running this pages can run php.

Comment: I will try the iframe then. I think I should be able to work within those limitations for the simple application I want to create.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft IIS webserver supports PHP so you can create PHP pages (Having the extension .php) that are then interpreted as they would be on Apache. You can't mix and match PHP within other types of file because the script will never get interpreted. Check with your ISP though because not all have PHP enabled.